# How to change the romanized conversion table in mozc?

Tags: discussion

With Anthy, I had a custom table, such that `<l>` was used for `<ん>` for instance. I found this more convenient than using a context-sensitive system or pressing `<nn>` all the time, but I can't find any place nor on the internet where changing this is possible with Mozc? Is this not possible at all with Mozc or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I since found it, the confusion is because it cannot be found in the normal fcitx option dialog, and instead Mozc has it's own, which must be started in a most arcane way:

```
/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog
```

The flag is even required.